# How to scroll through a div horizontally with arrows using marginLeft instead of scrollLeft?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll my div horizontally with arrows by changing the margin of the div as using scrollLeft property needs me to set overflow as hidden on the div, which doesn't go well with my hover effects.

But I can't figure out how to set it in a way that the div while scrolling horizontally perfectly aligns with the window on both left and right sides of the div, on both pc and mobile.

I managed to make the left arrow stop working initially when the margin is zero by calculating the actual margin set with css('margin-left'). But I can't figure out how to do the same for the right arrow i.e when the div reaches the end of scrolling.

Here is what the div looks like (the ones below the large grid, with multiple items) - https://netflix-clone-by-shivam.herokuapp.com/

```
import $ from "jquery";

export const LeftArrow = node => {
  var move = node.current;
  var margin =  parseInt($(move).css('margin-left'));
  console.log(margin)
  if(margin < 0) {
    $(move).animate(
      {
        marginLeft: "+=330px"
      },
      "slow"
    );
}
};

export const RightArrow = node => {
  var move = node.current;
  var margin = parseInt($(move).css('margin-left'));
  console.log(margin)
    $(move).animate(
      {
        marginLeft: "-=330px"
      },
      "slow"
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate all the images together, minus the last one.

```
 var images = $(move).find('.movie-image');
 var width = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < (images.length -1); i++){
   width += images.eq(i).width();
 }
```

Then only animate if the margin is smaller than the width.

```
if(margin < width){
  $(move).animate({
    marginLeft: "-=330px"
  }, "slow");
}
```